# Odd filtering behavior of Google Map markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**Updated Example:**

> http://jsfiddle.net/7Cwbn/62/

*You can click on the markers*

*Hold **Ctrl** to select multiple options*

## UPDATE:

I've fiddled with the script some more and replaced `jQuery.inArray()` with `array_diff()` function as a test statement inside the `if`s.

Also I've change the `if` logic a bit. I tried the new code with filtering **just** the houses and it seems to work, **but** when I enable the same filtering code for condos too - filtering gets messed up a little.

*For example*: If I select everything from **Features** - nothing shows up on the map. But some markers should have showed up since I have at least two of them that have all of the three available features.

```
$(markers.houses).each(function(index, elem) {
        if ((array_diff(selectedFeatures, elem.features).length === 0) && (array_diff(selectedNearby, elem.nearby).length === 0)) {
            if (!markers.houseMarkers[index].visible) {
                markers.houseMarkers[index].setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    });
$(markers.condos).each(function(index, elem) {
        if ((array_diff(selectedFeatures, elem.features).length === 0) && (array_diff(selectedNearby, elem.nearby).length === 0)) {
            if (!markers.condoMarkers[index].visible) {
                markers.condoMarkers[index].setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

> **FIG 1.1** - *Slice of filtering code for houses and condos*

Comment: I'd suggest extensively using console.log to try and figure out what's going on at every stage of the execution of your filtering

Comment: @duncan: Really? I wouldn't think of that myself.

Comment: and so the results of that logging told you what?

Comment: @duncan: `selectedFeatures is null` if nothing is selected in **Features** box or if nothing is selected in both **Features** and **Nearby** boxes. `selectedNearby is null` if nothing is selected in **Nearby** box. `selectedFeatures is not defined` if both **Features** and **Nearby** have something selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo here (**selectedFeaturess**) which might have something to do with it:

```
 if (jQuery.inArray(selectedFeaturess[i], elem.features) !== -1 || jQuery.inArray(selectedFeatures[i], elem.features) > -1) {
```

Also this isn't going to help I suspect:

```
<option value="Wendy's">Harveys</option>
```

Code like this:

```
if (jQuery.inArray(selectedFeatures[i], elem.features) !== -1 || jQuery.inArray(selectedFeatures[i], elem.features) > -1) {
```

Can be simplified to just:

```
if (jQuery.inArray(selectedFeatures[i], elem.features) !== -1) {
```

Because if it's > -1 then it's !== -1, so the 2nd clause is redundant.  e.g. if you had it = 0, then the first part of the IF clause fires and no need for the 2nd part of the IF statement to be executed.

And finally, here's a rewrite of your $(document).ready() function.  The main problem was how you were looping over the elements in your arrays.  Instead of treating them as jquery selectors and doing a .each() on them, you just need to do a simple For loop.  But you can use the jquery selector to check their lengths.  This works for me (I also renamed Wendy's to Harveys in the options).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //$('#filter').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#filter').click(function(e) {
        // prevent refreshing of the page
        e.preventDefault();

        // close all infoWindows
        infowindow.close();

        // hide all markers
        $(markers.houses).each(function(index, elem) {
            markers.houseMarkers[index].setVisible(false);
        });
        $(markers.condos).each(function(index, elem) {
            markers.condoMarkers[index].setVisible(false);
        });

        // get the selected features from select box
        var selectedFeatures = $("#features").val();
        var selectedNearby = $("#nearby").val();

        // for each house element...
        $(markers.houses).each(function(index, elem) {
            //first filter by selected features
            if ($(selectedFeatures).length) {
                for (var i = 0; i < selectedFeatures.length; i++) {       
                    if (jQuery.inArray(selectedFeatures[i], elem.features) !== -1) {    
                        if (!markers.houseMarkers[index].visible) {
                            markers.houseMarkers[index].setVisible(true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //then filter by nearby selections
            if ($(selectedNearby).length) {
                for (var i = 0; i < selectedNearby.length; i++) {
                    if (jQuery.inArray(selectedNearby[i], elem.nearby) !== -1) {
                        // if marker is not visible, but meets the filtering criteria - show it
                        // otherwise leave it as it is
                        if (!markers.houseMarkers[index].visible) {
                            markers.houseMarkers[index].setVisible(true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // for each condo element...
        $(markers.condos).each(function(index, elem) {

            // first filter by selected features
            if ($(selectedFeatures).length) {
                 for (var i = 0; i < selectedFeatures.length; i++) {       
                    if (jQuery.inArray(selectedFeatures[i], elem.features) !== -1) {
                        // if marker is not visible, but meets the filtering criteria - show it
                        // otherwise leave it as it is
                        if (!markers.condoMarkers[index].visible) {
                            markers.condoMarkers[index].setVisible(true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //then filter by nearby selections
            if ($(selectedNearby).length) {
                for (var i = 0; i < selectedNearby.length; i++) {
                    if (jQuery.inArray(selectedNearby[i], elem.nearby) !== -1) {
                        // if marker is not visible, but meets the filtering criteria - show it
                        // otherwise leave it as it is
                        if (!markers.condoMarkers[index].visible) {
                            markers.condoMarkers[index].setVisible(true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This fixed the issue with condo markers not showing up, but the rest of the issues still persist.